# How to return a constant value, not creating a new object every time

Tags: java

I have a function used to populate data into map

```
public final class ConfigurationService {
   public final RMap populateCache(RedissonClient client) {
      RMap map = client.getMap("Config");
      map.put("key1", "value1");
      map.put("key2", "value2"):
      return map;
   }
}
```

and I call that function in my main class, how can I make it return a constant value, not creating a new object every time

does change the function populateCache() return a map works?

```
ConfigurationService configurationService = new ConfigurationService()
configurationService.populateCache(client)
```

Comment: You can check singleton pattern https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton

Comment: Can you describe what it is that you are trying to do? You're asking how populateCache() should not create a new instance each time, but your code does exactly that.

Comment: After your edit, what happens if you call configurationService.populateCache(client) again? populateCache() is creating a new RMap instance each time you call it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your intention. Anyway, to answer your question, I notice that your method doesn't need to instantiate any new object or using `ConfigurationService` instance members at all, thus you can just declare your method as static:

```
public final static RMap populateCache(RedissonClient client) {
...
}
```

So, when you have to invoke the method, there's no need to create a new `ConfigurationService` object, but you just do this way:

```
RMap map = ConfigurationService.populateCache(client);
```

I think that works fine for your specific case, as the `populateCache` looks just an utility method, so it's ok to declare it as `static` and make it manipulate an object that you pass in input.

Answer (score 0):

ConfigurationService.populateCache(client);